# Shopify .NET API - Invalid request: The Shopify API application does not support oauth

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, oauth, shopify

I am trying to build a website were I can get all my information from my Shopify store using there API.

I have downloaded the .NET example from [here](https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/shopify.net), and added to the config file my API Key and secret key, when I run the test application after putting in my site name it redirects me to shopify.com control panel of my store but I writes on the screen 'It appears that an error has occured' and it says that :

**Invalid request: The Shopify API application does not support oauth**

I will appropriate it if any one can please try helping me and direct me to find the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Private apps don't require an OAuth access token for authentication, you can use a api-key, password combination.

for ex:
https://API-KEY:PASSWORD@YOUR-TEST-SHOP.myshopify.com/admin/orders.xml

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I dont really have much of experience calling API, do you know were I can find a easy and basic example written in .NET for me to start from? all the examples I found are all with OAuth.

Comment: thanks again. I know what URL I need to get the info, but I am not sure of how to write the code all around it in order to get the data, I am now trying to use `WebRequest` but I get on error back **The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized**, any idea? that's y I would love to find a working application i can start working from .

Answer (score 4):

As kobe says, private apps are much simpler.  Here's an [example](http://seriouscodage.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/using-shopify-api-from-net.html):

```
public string GetCustomers()
{
    const string url = "https://your-store.myshopify.com/admin/customers.json";

    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.ContentType = "application/json";
    req.Credentials = GetCredential(url);
    req.PreAuthenticate = true;

    using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
        if (resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string message = String.Format("Call failed. Received HTTP {0}", resp.StatusCode);
            throw new ApplicationException(message);
        }

        var sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

private static CredentialCache GetCredential(string url)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
    var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    credentialCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("your-api-key", "your-password"));
    return credentialCache;
}
```

Get the credentials by going to http://your-store.myshopify.com/admin/apps, and clicking "Create a private API key" at the bottom.